# Creating data similar to coalash in R

Tags: r, matlab, simulation

I am trying to create a dataset similar to `coalash` in R taken from [Gomez and Hazen](http://www.osti.gov/energycitations/product.biblio.jsp?osti_id=7196441).  Actually, I have some spatial data in matlab which I want to import in R to calculate the variogram. I saw an example [here](http://ifasstat.ifas.ufl.edu/STA%206934SP10/notes/Fitting%20a%20model%20variogram.pdf). However, I am not able to create something like the `coalash` data in R. I have imported my matrix from matlab to R. But how can I convert it to something similar to `coalash` in R?

This is what they are doing in R. Any suggestions?

```
library(gstat)
coordinates(coalash) = ~ x + y
plot(variogram(log(coalash) ~ 1, coalash))
```

Comment: you can always bootstrap from the data. Alternately, you can randomly generate coordinates, generate random normal outcome data, and use the Cholesky decomposition of an AR1 correlation matrix to create spatial correlation.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(sp)
coalsp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coalash[1:2], data=coalash[3])
plot(variogram(log(coalash) ~ 1, coalsp))
```

I'm wondering if you had failed to load package::sp? (That was part of the directions in the cited example.) When I run your code after loading `sp` I get no errors.